# How to find a HTML element by same element from different parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to select a element by a same element and parent elements were different(which elements contains same attribute and values) without using loop. For example,

`Code is:`[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pranath/1h941p49/5/)

Please suggest me to getting element in any other way..

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle? Duplicate ID's like you have are an awful idea. I'm guessing thats where your problem is coming from.

Comment: how do you establish equivalence?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: Agree with @ZakariaAcharki also fix your **double quote** in the tags attributes...

Comment: Hi JF, here is my JSfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/pranath/1h941p49/5/

Comment: @Zakaria, i have share jsfiddle sample. please look at this

Comment: @JF it, one more info is more inner level element doesn't have id, this is only contains the content. Please check my updated sample link.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, you basically wants to get the intersection of elements from two set of `tuples`

try

```
$(variable1st).find("Tuple").filter($(var2nd).find( "Tuple" ));
```

or

```
var tupleSet1 = $(variable1st).find( "Tuple" );
var tupleSet2 = $(var2nd).find( "Tuple" );
var finalOutput = tupleSet1.filter(function(el) {
    return tupleSet2.indexOf(el) != -1
});
```

updating your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/1h941p49/7/) as

```
function change(){

   var tuple1 = $("#var1")[0].outerHTML;
   console.log($(tuple1).find("tuple"));
   var tuple2 = $("#var2")[0].outerHTML;
   console.log($(tuple2).find("tuple"));
   var commonTuples = $(tuple1).find("tuple").filter( function(i,v){

      console.log( v.outerHTML );
      console.log( tuple2.indexOf( v.outerHTML ) );
        return tuple2.indexOf( v.outerHTML ) != -1 ;

   } );    

   alert( commonTuples.text() );

 }
```

Comment: 1 st solution not meet my requirement, and i need without looping like 1st one.

Comment: yes this can be achieved my requirement, but i would like without looping. Need to achieve by selector.

Comment: @Pranath these tuples don't have unique ids so I don't think you can do so by selector. Is there a restriction or any specific reason of not using looping?

Comment: Yes. having huge set of elements which is comparing with large set of items from other element. So this will trigger performance problem.

Comment: @Pranath even jquery selectors internally loop/traverse through DOM. I don't think this iteration is going to cause a huge performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for 1st tuple with matching div id then this should work.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtechdev/86cLbmoy/)

```js
var var1st = $("#first");
var var2nd = $("#second");

var match = var1st.find("#" + var2nd.find("Tuple:first-child > div").attr("id")).parent();

var (match.html());
```

```html
<Tuples id="first">
  <Tuple>
    <div id="1"></div>
  </Tuple>
  <Tuple>
    <div id="2"></div>
  </Tuple>
  <Tuple>
    <div id="3"></div>
  </Tuple>
  <Tuple>
    <div id="4"></div>
  </Tuple>
</Tuples>

<Tuples id="second">
  <Tuple>
    <div id="1"></div>
  </Tuple>
  <Tuple>
    <div id="2"></div>
  </Tuple>
</Tuples>
```

Comment: Element index will change, not particular for 1st element. Also  we couldn't find using div's id because some of the same set doesn't have id.

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique in a document. i.e., you cannot give same ID for two elements.

Instead give same class names, like

```
<tuple>
  <div class="1">1st</div>
</tuple>
```

Then you can directly select as $(".1"). This will return an array of nodes having the same class name. You can iterate over this array and get the text. Hope this helps.

Comment: Some HTML element doesn't have id